# Simplifying a sum

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Suppose we have $X_1 = \dots = X_{T-1} = -1$ and $X_T = 1$, calculate $$S_T = \sum_{k=1}^T(2^{k}-1)X_k$$

I got the answero f $- \sum_{k=1}^{T-1}(2^k-1) + 2^T - 1$ is there a quick way of simplifying $$\sum_{k=1}^{T-1}(2^k-1)$$

Comment: $2 + 2^2 + \cdots + 2^{T - 1} = 2(2^{T-1}-1)$.
General: $a + ar + ar^2 + \cdots + ar^{n - 1} = a\dfrac{r^n - 1}{r - 1}$.

Comment: @M.Vinay where from

Comment: Let $S = a + ar + \cdots + ar^{n-1}$. Then $rS = ar + ar^2 + \cdots + ar^n = S - a + ar^n \implies$ $rS - S = a(r^n - 1) \implies$ $S = a \dfrac{r^n - 1}{r - 1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^{T-1} (2^k - 1) & = \sum_{k=1}^{T-1} 2^k - (T-1)\\
& = \frac{2(1-2^{T-1})}{1-2} - (T-1)\\[0.5em]
& = 2^T - 2 - T+1\\[0.5em]
& = 2^T - T -1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

It is a geometric series summation.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. One may recall the standard **finite** evaluation:

> $$
> 1+x+x^2+...+x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}, \quad x \neq1 \tag1
> $$

which one may prove by just expanding
$$
(1-x)(1+x+x^2+...+x^n).
$$